# How to create a UISegmentedControl with different font in each segment?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

How do I create a UISegmentedControl with different font in each segment?
I know I can use `setTitleTextAttributes: forState:`, but this sets the same font for all buttons at once. 
I'm trying to create something like this:
[image: example]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `– setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:` of UISegmentedControl, and passing him a custom draw of NSString by using one of NSString UIKit Additions.

Take a look at this link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:` takes an `NSString`. How does this support using a different font for each string? Perhaps you means to use `setImage:forSegmentAtIndex:` after creating an image from the string drawn with the desired font.

Comment: You have to draw each of your strings manually with NSString UIKit additions method like `– drawInRect:withFont:`(look at the link for more information). But this is a tricky way and indeed it would be easier if you can just used `setImage:forSegmentAtIndex:`

Comment: What you propose is impossible using `setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:`.  Using `setImage:forSegmentAtIndex:` is not only easier, it is the only solution.